# How to use Sinonjs with bruch-with-chaplin boilerplate

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sinon, brunch, chaplinjs

I started out with the [Brunch-with-Chaplin](https://github.com/paulmillr/brunch-with-chaplin%20'brunch-with-chaplin') boilerplate, but i wanted to add sinon and qunit to the mix. So i added them to the `bower.json` and installed them with `bower install <lib>`. It work all very smooth but now i want to access the functionality like this:

```
Model = require './model'

module.exports = class Collection extends Chaplin.Collection
  # Mixin a synchronization state machine.
  # _(@prototype).extend Chaplin.SyncMachine
  # initialize: ->
  #   super
  #   @on 'request', @beginSync
  #   @on 'sync', @finishSync
  #   @on 'error', @unsync

  # Use the project base model per default, not Chaplin.Model

    model: Model

    initialize: ->
        @on 'request', @reply

    reply: ->
        console.log QUnit # this works
        console.log Sinon # this error's
        console.log 'requested'
```

UPDATE:

When i manually build with `brunch build` i got the error

```
error: [Error: Component JSON file     
"/Users/Simon/Development/myparcel/data/myparcel/bower_components/sinon/.bower.json"
must have `main` property. 
See https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components#README]
```

So i added `"main":"sinon.js"` to the file without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a little more you need to change `"sinon.js"` to `"lib/sinon.js"` and
`console.log Sinon` to `console.log sinon` because Sinon uses the `sinon` global not `Sinon`